# How to make a discord bot send a message if someone in particulary sends a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want for example the bot to say "shut up" when a person in particular sends a message

This is the code by now:

```
if message.author == (317330140486959106):
        await message.channel.send("shut up")
```

Comment: try `message.author.id`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the on_message event from discord.py:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author.id == 317330140486959106:
       await message.channel.send("shut up")
```

where client is your discord bot client.

Beside that you should pay attention which information you post here. Now everybody knows that you want to target this user and can get his name with a discord id lookup or something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that `message.author` is of type `Member`, so you are comparing an object to a number -- also, there is no need to put parentheses around a number.

In order to properly process every message sent, you must use the `on_message` event which waits/listens for a message to be sent in any servers the bot may be into.

A working code would look something like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    targetId = 10101010
    if message.author.id == targetId:
        await message.channel.send("Shut up")
```